# NSIS Uninstaller does not delete directory

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I am using NSIS for My Installer.
When I uninstall, at the end I want to remove the installation directory and all it's content.
I am using the following code

`Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"
RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"`

And I notice that the installer deletes all the files in the directory, and then crashes.
(i've added log in between the lines and it is not called, The directory stays)

What could be the reason for it to crash like this?
I've shutted down the service, and the process, and don't think that anything is in use.

Thank you

EDIT:
Maybe it's because I am deleting the Uninstaller.exe? I tried calling `ExecWait` to a batch file that deletes the folder and it also stops working after the delete

Comment: You added some logging between those two lines and there is nothing printed. In other words, you are saying the Delete instructions crashes? Can you provide some more details like NSIS version and Windows version?

Comment: Yes!
Windows 7 HomePremium 32bit. The MakeNSISW version is 2.3.2 (This is the NSIS version?)

Comment: No, we need the NSIS version, run MakeNSIS /version (MakeNSISW should display it in the bottom left of the main window). If it is not v2.46 then you should upgrade/downgrade...

Comment: Oh, ok here it is: 3.0b0, Downgrading....

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the official docs:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/RMDir

You have to specify `/r` flag to remove not empty directories and `/REBOOTOK` to remove any directories that can't be removed at run time and will be removed during OS reboot.

Additionally you can't delete current working directory that is set by `SetOutPath` command. You need to change it first. See my unistall section below:

```
Section "Uninstall"

  Delete "$DESKTOP\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANY_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk"
  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANY_NAME}"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
  SetOutPath "$PROGRAMFILES"
  RMDir /r /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR"
  
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\your app name here"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\your app name here"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: SetOutPath "$PROGRAMFILES" is the key.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little snippet of my uninstaller section.

I would assume you must remove every single thing you create, so this isn't a wildcard solution.

```
Section Uninstall

Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\your app\Uninstall.lnk"

Delete "$DESKTOP\your app.lnk"

Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\your app\your app.lnk"


RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\your app"

RMDir "$INSTDIR\folder"

RMDir "$INSTDIR"

SetAutoClose true

Section End
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this script to Uninstall all the files and delete the folder using NSIS.

```
Section "Uninstall"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\*.*"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"
    DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\APPName"
    RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"
SectionEnd
```

Hope this helps.